# Generating FontMetrics from java

Tags: java

am working on generating font metrics on server-side by giving ttf file as input.

Iam trying to Font , FontRenderContext , GlyphVector and GlyphMetrics classes.I have also tried Apache FOP but the metrics generated are not help me.

Would like to know if the following operations are possible?

1. given unicode , how do I know if this has an independent glyph or it has to be compounded with another glyph etc.
2. Is it possible to generate font metrics with all these details and use it for calculating my line width
3. How do I know if a glyph is a ligature and how can I get the glyph width post rendering?
4. Can I assume that a compounded glyph will always appear to the right?

any pointers to these will help?

Comment: Much of what you're asking is basically what a font layout/rendering engine needs to know. And it's *terribly* complicated, especially if you plan to support non-latin scripts. My suggestion: don't ever handle individual codepoints and/or glyphs, instead request line metrics of entire strings you're trying to render/measure.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.The problem for me is I need to persist these metrics for rendering the content in another client and for printing. Should I persist the metrics for word or what is the best way to persist the metrics if going by codepoint is complex.